# How to get data from associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to write PHP for get data from this.

```
{"room":[{"single_room":1,"twin_room":3}]}{"total_amount":[{"amount":20899}]}{"travelernum":[{"total":1}]}
```

I tried like this

```
$BookingDetail["room"]["single_room"];
```

but got result like this

> Illegal string offset 'room'

and

> Illegal string offset 'single_room'

How to solve it.

Comment: That's not an array.

Comment: json_decode() and var_dump($var)

Comment: Those are 3 json 's concatenated, how do you obtain those ? do you have them in different variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... you need to decode the json, you get a PHP object and then you can access each element ..

```
<?php

$str = '{"room":[{"single_room":1,"twin_room":3}]}{"total_amount":[{"amount":20899}]}{"travelernum":[{"total":1}]}';

$json = json_decode($str);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";

echo $json->room->single_room;
```

By the way, I think your json is invalid. You can check this out at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It won't work because those are 3 json's concatenated

Comment: not a valid json, will not work. it's a combo of 3 json encoded data

Answer (score 0):

The string you are using looks like JSON but it doesn't check out as valid. See [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)... Editing it to make it valid (single line)...

```
{"room": [{"single_room": 1, "twin_room": 3}], "total_amount": [{"amount": 20899}], "travelernum": [{"total": 1 }]}
```

OR (Multi-Line)...

```
{
    "room": [{
        "single_room": 1,
        "twin_room": 3
    }],
    "total_amount": [{
        "amount": 20899
    }],
    "travelernum": [{
        "total": 1
    }]
}
```

If this is the format all your strings are in, you can manipulate them into valid JSON by first by using...

```
$original_string = '{"room":[{"single_room":1,"twin_room":3}]}{"total_amount":[{"amount":20899}]}{"travelernum":[{"total":1}]}';
$new_string = str_replace("}{", ",", $original_string);  // replace }{ with ,
```

Once your string is in valid JSON format, converting to a PHP array because rather simple, use something like this...

```
$BookingDetail = json_decode($new_string, true);  //true param gets assoc array
```

I tested all the code above and it works.See PHP json_decode() function reference for more detail on converting JSON strings to PHP Arrays.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php